# UIButton got his default text when clicked

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

while i create my UIButton on Interface builder, i put a text like `Button 1`.

when i launch the application, i change programmatically the text to something else like this:

```
btn1.titleLabel.text=@"Hello";
```

Everything is ok until i press the button, it got its default text which is `Button 1`.

My purpose is that, if the text has been changed programmatically, it can't get its default text value when i press the button, i mean the text `Hello` should remain. How can i do that please? Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't change the textLabel directly, use setTitle:forState: instead...

[See UIButton reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:)

Answer (score 3):

```
[btn1 setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 setTitle: @"Hello" forState: UIControlStateSelected];
[btn1 setTitle: @"Hello" forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
[myButton setTitle: @"myTitle" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

use  UIControlStateNormal to set your title.

there are couple of states that UIbuttons provide, you can have a look:

[myButton setTitle: @"myTitle" forState: UIControlStateApplication];
[myButton setTitle: @"myTitle" forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
[myButton setTitle: @"myTitle" forState: UIControlStateReserved];
[myButton setTitle: @"myTitle" forState: UIControlStateSelected];
[myButton setTitle: @"myTitle" forState: UIControlStateDisabled];
```